# Python3 triggers an array error even tho i am not using an array. Probably my syntax is wrong but i do not find the error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Hi there i have written some code for my physics studys and i am fairly new to python.

Can someone explain to me why

[code]while s < 3.05 and t < 1e-7 :[/code]

triggers

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

i googled for quite a while and searched stack but i have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: i do not think it is a duplicate because what i am using is not an array. For some reason Python thinks it is an array.

Probably i did something wrong but i have no idea what

Comment: that's ok if `s`  and `t` are scalars.  Look at `s<3.05` alone. Does it make sense to apply a `while` or `and` to that result?

Comment: While `s` and `t` start off as scalars, something is change one or both into a `numpy` array.  And as indicated in the duplicate, performing `if`, `while` and `and` operations on a boolean array doesn't work.  You need to figure out, from the full error message. where the error occurs (which function), and figure out why `s` (or `t`) becomes an array (maybe `dt` is also an array, etc).

Comment: You are calling `Ek` with arrays.  `E` is then an array.  `v` is derived from that, as is  `ds`.  So on the next loop `s+ds` is also an array.  `Ek` may work fine with scalar `E` and `p`, but it is not setup to work with arrays.

Comment: that is the problem. I have no idea what may cause this.


  File "/tmp/mozilla_woelki0/arrayerror.py", line 67, in Ek
    while s < 3.05 and t < 1e-7 :

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

This is everything i get as an error.

I do not find where to get a grip at this.

I highly appreciate you trying to help

Comment: I've reopened this.  While the duplicate explains the error message, it doesn't explain why it occurs in this code.  And doesn't help this beginner debug the problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: thx for reopening. an instant duplicate would not have been a great start for me here.

sadly i cannot use the reputation meter due to beeing new.

Answer (score 0):

When I copy-n-paste the code if runs (thankfully) and produces the error message:

```
1231:~/mypy$ python3 stack53381357.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack53381357.py", line 105, in <module>
    Z = Ek(X, Y)
  File "stack53381357.py", line 67, in Ek
    while s < 3.05 and t < 1e-7 :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Note that the full message does tell us where the problem is - in the `Ek` function at line 67.  That is relevant information.

That confirms my comment - `Ek` is called with array arguments, and that propagates through the loop, changing `s` to an array.

When I add a print to the end of the `Ek` loop:

```
    print(type(s), s.shape)
```

I get, before the error:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (100, 100)
```

So, yes, `s` has changed from a scalar to a `numpy` array, the same shape as the `X` and `Y` arrays you passed to `Ek`.

Your 3 functions appear to have been written for scalar inputs.  I'm not going to try to figure out how they should work with the `meshgrid` inputs.  You could iterate over the `pa` and `Ea` elements.  Or you could modify the functions so they do behave when given array values.  At the very least the

```
while (s<3.05) and (t<1e-7):
```

has to be written to be meaningful when `s` is an array.  There may be other problems with array inputs.